# Try food from someone, Try someone's food, Try food from someone's plate

Tags: word-usage

> I usually get the same thing at my favorite fast food place. But if my friend gets something I've never tried before, I'll **try some from them**, and see if I want to get it the next time.

Does it sound natural? It doesn't flow well. What's the best way to express it?

As in "Trying food from someone", "try someone's food", "try food from someone's food".

I know that "I'll have some of their food" works, but I'm looking for something along the lines of "try".

Comment: If you mean you eat a little from their plate/box, you can say "I'll try some of theirs."

Answer (score 1):

"I'll try some of their food" works fine, and since "food" is implied you could say "try some of theirs".

Comment: Does it work with a drink too? "I'll try some of their drink."

Comment: So doesn't "Try some from them" work?

Comment: It's understandable, but it doesn't work very well.  It is usually "some of something"

Comment: And does it work with a drink? (As in the first comment)